# Is there a simple way to update the data of a form rendered with django-forms

Tags: django, django-crispy-forms

i am fairly new to django and im trying to render a django form and update its content with an ajax request to an API.

So i got a form like this:

```
from django import forms
from models import ExampleModel

class ExampleForm(forms.ModelForm):
    name=forms.CharField()
    comment=forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea())
    class Meta:
        model = ExampleModel
        fields=("name","comment")
```

got my data from the API like this:

```
from forms import ExampleForm
from models import ExampleModel
def apiGetExampleData(request,name):
    data=ExampleModel.objects.filter(name=name).values(*getFormFields(ExampleForm()))
    #if there is a better way to get the data, would be thankful to know :)
    JsonResponse(data[0])

def getFormFields(form):
    output=[]
    for element in form:
        output+=[element.name]
    return output
```

Now i got the form (which renders fine), and a way to get the data.
So, is there some predefined way to apply data in json format to a form in Javascript?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it like:

```
$.ajax({
          ...
          success: function(data) {
               Object.entries(obj).forEach(([key, value]) => {
                     $(`#exampleform [name=${key}]`).val(value);
          });
          }
        });
```

If anyone knows a better way, let me know !